# Upgrade to 18.04 LTS from 16.04 LTS broke VMware Workstation 12.5.9

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, vmware-workstation

After upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS, VMware Workstation 12.5.9 will not start. I uninstalled VMware then reinstalled it. Still get this message:

/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-modconfig: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0` with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1` for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime`

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal end execute the command

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

TL;DR

When the kernel is updated, VMWare must be relinked against changed modules.  The program listed above accomplishes this function, and older version of VMWare can be reconfigured with `sudo /usr/bin/vmware-config.pl`.

Source of information:  [VMware Knowledge Base](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1002411)

Comment: vmware-modconfig gives the message "Failed to get gcc information". /usr/bin/vmware-config.pl does not exist.

Comment: The "failed to get gcc information" is concerning - tdo ou have build-essential intsalled?  I would be tempted to `sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential`

Comment: I reinstalled build-essential and tried again. Get the same "Failed to get gcc information" message. I've since upgraded to vmware workstation 15.0.3. This has fixed the problem.